# With rectangle print the sum of coordinates or different id

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm trying to create a few random rectangles (only require to create 9-10 rectangle rather than doing it randomly) and then try to print different number with each of them. I'm new to latex and unable to achieve it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
          \foreach \j in {0,...,2}
              \node [small-node] (n-\i\j) at (\i + 0.50*rand + 1,\j + 0.50*rand + 1) {$n\i\j}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm trying to print n_1, .. n_10. But this is printing concat of both i and j, i have tried `\value{}` and then add but no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible (pure TikZ) solution is to calculate the progressive number as `3 * \j + \i + 1`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
    small-node/.style = {draw, rectangle},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \prog (initially 0) using int(3 * \j + \i + 1)] in {0,...,2}
        \node [small-node] (n-\i\j) at (\i + 0.50*rand + 1,\j + 0.50*rand + 1) {$n\prog$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. = I've used `beamer` because you put it as tag (before Torbjørn T.'s edit) and I invented the `small-node` style: next time, please post a complete MWE, not only a code snippet.

Comment: Yes. The point that i have added tag beamer is for the reason. I would keep this in mind now on.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome! With a complete MWE is much easier to reply quickly :)

Comment: Note that you don't actually need the `calc` library for any of that. (@Pushpa I removed the `beamer` tag because the class seemed irrelevant to the question, the solutions doesn't depend on it.)

Comment: Nope, that's part of the `pgf` math engine, same as e.g. `cos`. Just try your code without it. The `calc` library is for coordinate calculations using `($...$)` and, I believe, the `let` syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a new counter, and increase that by 1 every time you go through the inner loop. `\arabic{countername}` prints the value as an Arabic number.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcounter{rectanglecount}
\foreach \i in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \j in {0,...,2}
    {
    \stepcounter{rectanglecount}
    \node [draw] (n-\i\j) at (\i + 0.50*rand + 1,\j + 0.50*rand + 1) {$n_{\arabic{rectanglecount}}$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want the sum of `\i` and `\j`, you'll need to tell LaTeX to evaluate that sum somehow, for example as below. Note that `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` makes an integer, with `\pgfmathsetmacro` you'll get a number with decimals.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcounter{rectanglecount}
\foreach \i in {0,...,2}
     \foreach \j in {0,...,2}
     {
     % save result of \i +\j in \tmpval, as integer
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmpval}{\i+\j}
     \node [draw] (n-\i\j) at (\i + 0.50*rand + 1,\j + 0.50*rand + 1) {$n_{\tmpval}$};
     }             
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. Is it possible to make sure that no both overlaps ?

Comment: @Pushpa That is a very different question, which is probably a lot harder to answer. I suggest you make a new question specifically about that problem, I don't think I'll be able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version using an alternative drawing approach: [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) wrapped up in [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en).  Compile with `lualatex`, follow the links for more information about these tools.

I've included a very simple "no overlaps" routine.

[image: Non-overlapping, random boxes]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef no_overlaps = 
    save i; i = 0;
    save overlaps; boolean overlaps; overlaps := false;
    forever:
        exitif not known nodes[incr i];
        overlaps := (xpart nodes[i] < x0 + bx) and (x0 - bx < xpart nodes[i])
                and (ypart nodes[i] < y0 + by) and (y0 - by < ypart nodes[i]);
        exitif overlaps;
    endfor
    not overlaps
enddef;

beginfig(1);
    pair nodes[];
    numeric N, s, bx, by;
    N = 15; s = 42; bx = 21; by = 13;
    for n=1 upto N:
        forever:
            x0 := s * normaldeviate;
            y0 := s * normaldeviate;
            exitif no_overlaps;
        endfor
        draw unitsquare shifted (-1/2,-1/2) xscaled bx yscaled by shifted z0;
        label("$n_{" & decimal n & "}$", z0);
        nodes[n] := z0;
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

#### Notes

- Variables: `nodes[]` is a list of pairs already chosen; `N` the number of boxes to draw; `s` a scale factor; `bx` and `by` the dimensions of the boxes to draw.
- Note that plain MP allows us to write `z0` as a shorthand for `(x0,y0)` (where 0 is any valid `suffix`).
- The inner loop of the main part picks random coordinates until there are no overlaps, using the `normaldeviate` primitive that returns a real number between about -4 and 4, normally distributed about zero.
- A box is then drawn at the chosen pair, and the pair is added to the `nodes[]` list.
- The `no_overlaps` function using the global variables `nodes`, `x0`, `y0`, `bx` and `by`.  It loops over the list of nodes until it finds an overlap or runs out of known nodes.
- The `incr i` syntax increments the index variable `i` in place (before use).